# Low volatility portfolio construction

Tags: python, pandas, portfolio

I want to test the low volatility factor for some market other than equities. Contradiccting finance 101, it has been Shown that low volatility stocks outperform high volatility stocks (see, for example, Baker, Malcolm, Brendan Bradley, and Jeffrey Wurgler (2011), “Benchmarks as Limits to Arbitrage: Understanding the Low-Volatility Anomaly”, Financial Analyst Journal, Vol. 67, No. 1, pp. 40–54.)

So what I want to do is construct the low vola factor by following the methodology of Jegadeesh and Titman (1993), namely raning stocks according to their previous j historical volatility and short top 30% (the most volatile) and Long the bottom 30% (the least volatile), and hold that Long-short Portfolio for k periods. Therefore, a 3-3 j-k Portfolio would mean, looking at the past 3 months of historical volatility (j), and hold that Portfolio for the following 3 months (k).

I have written some Code, and the j part Can be easily managed by simply increasing or decreasing the window of the rolling window vola calculation. The part I am struggling with is the k part, how this could be done. Unfortunately, I couldnt find many examples online.

In addition, I was wondering if my Code is correct or if I did any mistake, since it surprisingly did not work, regardless of the dataset I used. I am not sure whether this is the right place to ask, but if someone could take a look at it that would be great and might be helpful to others planning to implement a strategy like this as well.

Below is a simple working example with just 10 stocks. As I said, I want to implement it for some other assets, but this Code should work. You just have to use your own API key in line 16. Thanks a lot!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import quandl
import pickle
import scipy.optimize as sco
from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import shift
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


##################
# Low volatility #
##################

quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = 'Your key here'
stocks = ['MSFT','AAPL','AMZN','FB','BRK.B','JPM','GOOG','JNJ','V','PG','XOM']
data = quandl.get_table('WIKI/PRICES', ticker = stocks,
                        qopts = { 'columns': ['date', 'ticker', 'adj_close'] },
                        date = { 'gte': '2016-1-1', 'lte': '2019-11-3' }, paginate=True)

# with open("data.pkl", "wb") as pickle_file:
#     pickle.dump(data, pickle_file)
# with open("data.pkl", "rb") as pickle_file:
#     data = pickle.load(pickle_file)

data = data.pivot_table(index='date', columns='ticker', values='adj_close')
data = data.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="M")).mean() # convert from daily to monthly prices

returns = (np.log(data) - np.log(data.shift(1))).dropna()
stds = returns.rolling(12).std()
stds = stds.values # convert to numpy array

list = []
for x in range(0, stds.shape[0]): # for each row in std matrix, create decile buckets (dec -> breakpoint to the next bucket)
    for y in range(0,100,10):
        dec = np.percentile(stds[x], y)
        list.append(dec)

list = np.array(list) # convert list to numpy array
list = np.reshape(list, (stds.shape[0], -1)) # reshape the array such that it has the same format as returns (here: (26,10))

inds = []
for x in range(0, stds.shape[0]): # if the return is in the lower 30%, allocate a -1 to the asset. If it is in the upper 30%, allocate a 1. 0 otherwise.
    ind = np.digitize(stds[x], list[x])
    for x in range(0, ind.shape[0]):
        if ind[x] <= 3:
            ind[x] = 1
        elif ind[x] >= 8:
            ind[x] = -1
        else:
            ind[x] = 0
    inds.append(ind)

inds = np.array(inds)
inds = inds.astype(np.float32)

for x in inds: # divide -1, 1 and 0 by the respective total number of counts of -1, 1 and 0, such that they sum up to -1 and 1 (beta neutral long-short)
    ones = np.count_nonzero(x == 1) # count the number of 1
    minus_ones = np.count_nonzero(x == -1) # count the number of -1
    zeros = np.count_nonzero(x == 0) # count the number of 0
    for y in range(0, inds.shape[1]):
        if x[y] == 1:
            x[y] = x[y] / ones
        elif x[y] == -1:
            x[y] = x[y] / minus_ones
        else:
            x[y] = x[y] / zeros

returns = returns.shift(periods=-1).values # shift returns one period back, and create numpy array
pf_returns = np.sum((inds*returns), axis=1) # multiply returns with weights, and sum up
pf_returns = pd.DataFrame(pf_returns)

print("---")
print(pf_returns.describe())

# Plot
pf_returns_indexed = 100 * (1 + pf_returns).cumprod()
pf_returns_indexed = pf_returns_indexed.plot(linewidth=1.2) # change line width
plt.show()
```